# Apache Web-server, Tomcat : Changing load-balancing configuration so one Tomcat instance is in cold-standby

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have a load-balancing and fail-over setup configured on our Debian X64 based server. Right now, I have 2 Tomcat instances which are in load-balance and fail-over and running all the time. The requests are either served via Tomcat1(server1) or Tomcat2(server2).

There is an Apache web-server in front of the Tomcat's which acts as a load-balancer and failover, and is configured with mod_jk. Both the Tomcat's are connected to web-server via `AJP`.

Now, what I would like to do is, instead of running 2 instances of Tomcat, I would only like to run a single one. **When this instance dies or crashes, then the 2nd Tomcat instance is activated and requests are served with it.**

Here is the configuration :

workers.properties :

```
worker.list=loadbalancer
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
#worker.jk-status.read_only=true

worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status

worker.server1.port=8010
worker.server1.host=localhost
worker.server1.lbfactor=1
worker.server1.type=ajp13


worker.server2.port=8011
worker.server2.host=localhost
worker.server2.type=ajp13
worker.server2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2

worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=true
```

sites-enabled/000-default :

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com domain.com
JkMount /* loadbalancer
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

added this to apache2.conf :

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile   /etc/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkMount /* loadbalancer
JkMount /jkStatus jk-status
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Tomcat1 :

```
<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
<Connector port="8443" enableLookups="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compression="off" sslProtocols="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" 
 compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore" keystorePass="PASS" URIEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

Same above just with changed port-numbers in Tomcat2.

I hope there is sufficient information to deal with this problem. Kindly let me know. Thank you.

*Updated configuration*

```
  worker.list=loadbalancer
  worker.list=jk-status
  worker.jk-status.type=status
  worker.list=jk-manager
  worker.jk-manager.type=status

  worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
  worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2

  # Define the first member worker
  worker.server1.type=ajp13
  worker.server1.host=localhost
  worker.server1.port=8010
  # Define preferred failover node for worker1
  worker.server1.redirect=server2

  # Define the second member worker
  worker.server2.type=ajp13
  worker.server2.host=localhost
  worker.server2.port=8011
  # Disable worker2 for all requests except failover
  worker.server2.activation=disabled
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [mod_jk documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html), it seems you would use `distance` to create a hot-standby, by setting the distance greater:

> An integer number to express preferences between the balanced workers
>   of an lb worker. A load balancer will never choose some balanced
>   worker in case there is another usable worker with lower distance.
>   Only in case all workers below a given distance are in error, disabled
>   or stopped, workers of a larger distance are eligible for balancing.

In the [LoadBalancer Howto documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/loadbalancers.html) however, another approach is given:

> Finally you can also configure hot spare workers by using activation
>   set to disabled in combination with the attribute redirect added to
>   the other workers:

```
  # The advanced router LB worker
  worker.list=router
  worker.router.type=lb
  worker.router.balance_workers=worker1,worker2

  # Define the first member worker
  worker.worker1.type=ajp13
  worker.worker1.host=myhost1
  worker.worker1.port=8009
  # Define preferred failover node for worker1
  worker.worker1.redirect=worker2

  # Define the second member worker
  worker.worker2.type=ajp13
  worker.worker2.host=myhost2
  worker.worker2.port=8009
  # Disable worker2 for all requests except failover
  worker.worker2.activation=disabled
```

> The redirect flag on worker1 tells the load balancer to redirect the
>   requests to worker2 in case that worker1 has a problem. In all other
>   cases worker2 will not receive any requests, thus acting like a hot
>   standby.

Comment: What you gave is for mod_proxy, I have mod_jk. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @WeareBorg - hum, yes, was sleeping I guess. See edit.

Comment: Okay. HotStandby is also fine, any idea how I can make it to a cold-standby? The point of cold-stanbvy was to avoid running 2 JVM's, 2 Applications at the same time...

Comment: apache on its own won't just start your Tomcat application. You would need to write a script that monitors your Tomcat1 and if it's gone or not responding, fire up tomcat2 - at that point apache would see tomcat2 as there and use it. You'll have downtime obviously during the transition.

Comment: Hi, I just tried the configuration you gave, unfortunately it didn't work. One of the client was pushed to server-2, as verified from firebug. I have updated the main post and added the modified config at bottom, can you please check. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Okay, I had not added sticky session to your configuration, found that was the problem from this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345338/apache-http-load-balancing-failover-with-mod-jk Thank you.